# configure samba homes to different location

Tags: rhel, samba4

the default `/etc/samba/smb.conf` has

```
[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = No
    read only = No
```

my account as specified in `/etc/passwd` is `/home/ron` with account name `ron` and as such when I connect to linux from windows I see a `ron` folder that only I can access, and that goes to **/home/ron**.

Instead, I want that samba `ron` folder that shows up in Microsoft Windows when connecting to my samba server, to go to **/data/users/ron** instead.  How can I do that [in RHEL 8.9] ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want this only for user `ron`, just write a share section titled `[ron]`.

```
[ron]
    comment = Home Directory of Ron
    path = /data/users/ron
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = No 
    read only = No
    # adjust the share properties to suit your requirements
```

If you want everyone that has Samba access to have their Windows home folders at `/data/users/<username>` instead, add a path to the `[homes]` section, replacing the username with a `%S`:

```
path = /data/users/%S
```

From the `smb.conf` man page:

> When the connection request is made, the existing sections are scanned.  **If a match is found, it is used.** If no match is found, the requested section name is treated as a username and looked up in the local password file. If the name exists and the correct password has been given, a share is created by cloning the `[homes]` section.

Assuming this functional description is correct, an explicit share definition will always take priority over one generated using the `[homes]` template.